# ¿Cuándo debería votar?

Tags: discusión, faq, votos

Adaptación de [When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/182862)

---

Voy a detallar esto en múltiples partes para que sea más específico:

- Cuando debería votar en una pregunta:

  - ¿Cuáles son las calificaciones para que una pregunta requiera ser votada a favor?
  - ¿Cuándo no debería votar a favor una pregunta?
  - ¿Qué causaría que una pregunta sea votada en contra?

    - ¿Cómo debería actuar respecto a votar en contra una pregunta (esperar un corto tiempo para dar una oportunidad al OP en cambiarla o debería votar en negativo inmediatamente)?
  - ¿Cuándo no debería votar en contra una pregunta?
- Cuando debería votar en una respuesta:

  - ¿Cuáles son las calificaciones para una respuesta que requiere ser votada a favor?
  - ¿Cuándo no debería votar a favor en una respuesta?
  - ¿Qué causaría que una respuesta sea votada en contra?

    - ¿Cómo debería actuar respecto a votar en contra una respuesta (esperar un corto tiempo para dar una oportunidad al OP en cambiarla o debería votar en negativo inmediatamente)?
  - ¿Cuándo no debería vota en contra una respuesta?
- Cuando debería votar en un comentario:

  - Mientras los votos en los comentarios no afectan el puntaje de reputación, podría ser útil para los nuevos usuarios cuándo votar a favor por ellos.

Parece que una **lista completa y exhaustiva** de esto tendría un valor inestimable para los nuevos usuarios que buscan entender cómo funciona el sistema de votos.

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Muy buen trabajo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adaptación de [la respuesta aceptada para When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/182862)

---

Ten en cuenta que los votos son subjetivos en gran instancia, esta es *mi* lista de consideraciones.

Generalmente uso la idea "¿Esta publicación ayuda al sitio?" para juzgar los votos a favor y en contra hasta cierto punto. Esto se basa en la misma idea, expandido en diversos ítem.

Para los sitios beta [como el nuestro], hay que intentar ser más liberales al momento de votar en su etapa inicial, especialmente si no tienen muchos usuarios con alta reputación. Necesitas más gente con suficientes privilegios, y votar en publicaciones tipo no-está-mal-pero-tampoco-es-fantástica no es malo.

Intenta no dejar que otros factores como el puntaje de votos y otras respuestas influencien tu voto. Algunas veces, uno ve una publicación con muchísimos votos, y otra con varios votos pero no tanto como la anterior. No es algo que cause daño, pero es mejor primero juzgar por ti mismo. De manera similar, no dejes que quien publica o su reputación afecte tu voto. Lee la publicación con el mismo ojo crítico que con el que leerías la publicación de un usuario con 1 de reputación. Los expertos también pueden equivocarse. Votar en contra y mencionarlo en un comentario es exactamente lo que deberías hacer cuando ves una publicación errónea, **sin importar quién es el usuario**. StackExchange consiste en publicaciones, no usuarios. La reputación es una forma vaga de medir cuán involucrada está la comunidad y cuánto la comunidad confía en ti, pero realmente es un "mal necesario" ayudar al privilegio del sistema (y también es una especie de recompensa<sup>1</sup>). No lo uses para medir la calidad de la publicación. Si ves que algo está mal, comenta (y vota en contra si tienes la suficiente confianza).

Este es el caso opuesto de ["compensar un voto"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137315/downvoting-average-mass-upvote-question)<sup>2</sup>. Aquí, uno vota de manera que trae la publicación a lo que crees que es el puntaje correcto (al votar en contra masivamente preguntas mediocres con algo puntaje, etc.). Nuevamente, esto no es bueno. Intenta ignorar el puntaje actual cuando estés votando.

### Preguntas

Para votar en contra una pregunta, vota de inmediato. Si hay cosas por mejorar, comenta y vota en contra. Siempre puedes deshacer el voto en contra si se mejora. [Leer más](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)<sup>3</sup>.

#### Voto a favor

(elige una)

- La pregunta es clara y muestra esfuerzo de investigación.
- La pregunta es muy buena (en caso de preguntas divertidas, esto también puede funcionar)
- La pregunta  es útil para otros usuarios.

Nota: No votes a favor **por el solo hecho de** liberar una publicación de un voto negativo innecesario<sup>4</sup>.

#### Voto en contra

- No se comprende, no es clara.
- Es del tipo [dameelcódigoparfavar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dameelc%c3%b3digoparfavar) o similar sin mostrar esfuerzo del OP.
- Es **muy** localizada (muy probablemente le sea inútil al mundo).

Cabe resaltar que tiendo a votar a favor *preguntas* cuando sus respuestas explican algo muy bien. Es probable que esté mal, pero solo soy yo.

No votes en contra solo porque:

- La pregunta tiene errores gramaticales (mientras que se pueda entender).
- La pregunta tiene código malo (pero entendible); la pregunta usa malas prácticas de código; la premisa de que el programa está equivocado. En este caso, solo comenta "¿por qué no has hecho <foo>?". Si estás respondiendo, en su lugar puedes agregar eso a tu respuesta. **Recuerda, votar sirve para filtrar la calidad de *la publicación*, no *del código***. También hay uso legítimo para *todo*, inclusive [`eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)<sup>5</sup> o [scriptlets](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html#FlushTheBufferEarly).

### Respuestas

Con las respuestas, nuevamente, vota en contra de inmediato, comenta, deshaz el voto en contra si se arregla. Con los novatos, tiendo a ser más laxo, primero comento y luego decido votar en contra si no hacen caso. Pero nuevamente, esto es solo yo.

#### Voto a favor

Por supuesto, en cualquier caso, la respuesta **debe** responder la pregunta. Si no es por la última línea de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1065197), debió haber sido votada en contra (no que *debería haber sido*).

- La respuesta es clara.
- La respuesta explica el concepto de fondo. He visto muchas respuestas en SOes que dan la solución pero no el "por qué". A estas respuestas no suelo votarles en contra, pero tampoco a favor.

Nota: [No votes a favor *solamente* para liberar la respuesta de un voto negativo innecesario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137315/downvoting-average-mass-upvote-question).

#### Voto en contra

Al votar en contra, intenta comentar cuando sea aplicable.

- No responde la pregunta. Reporta bajo tu discreción.
- No tiene sentido.
- Publicaciones tipo [la bala más rápida del oeste (FGITW)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/182862) con una respuesta muy corta: Realmente, esto depende mucho de la respuesta.
- Respuestas de solo código: Una respuesta **debe ser útil** para las Personas Del Futuro™. Nadie va a tener el mismo código con el mismo problema en concreto ([Bueno, quizás no](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_del_mono_infinito)). Las Personas Del Futuro™ deberían tener una explicación de **por qué** el código está mal/tiene problemas/cualquier cosa que lo hace fallar, así ellos pueden aprender algo.
- [Respuestas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/182862)<sup>6</sup> [con solo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/182862)<sup>7</sup> [un enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
- Está mal (en tu opinión).
- Contiene malas prácticas de programación. A diferencia de las preguntas, la respuesta debería usar usar buenas prácticas. Para preguntas y respuestas, la *calidad de la publicación* se mide diferente. Para las preguntas, está asociado con la pregunta en concreto más que con el código. Para respuestas de solo código, las malas prácticas son... bueno... *malas*. En el caso de buenas explicaciones con mal código, votar en contra, comentar, deshacer el voto en contra. O abstenerse de votar y comentar. Cualquiera está bien, depende de ti.

NO votes en contra solo porque:

- Es un competidor. Se vota por la *calidad de la publicación*, y solo terminas dañando el sistema. Además, votar a favor de respuestas competidoras te da [algo brillante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship).
- Nuevamente, la gramática que no afecta mucho la comprensión.

### Comentarios

¿A quién le importa? Considera que en una publicación con muchos comentarios, los que se muestran son aquellos que serán votados a favor. Así que los comentarios que realmente mejoran la calidad de la publicación/ayudan al OP deberían ser votados a favor. Pero, como sabemos, nadie va a seguir eso -- `No hay suficiente jQuery` es una forma segura de obtener votos a favor en tu comentario. Y en MSOes, vota a favor un comentario solo sobre cualquier cosa.

---

Por traducir/reemplazar:

<sup>1</sup> [What aspects of psychology does Stack Overflow take advantage of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56469/what-aspects-of-psychology-does-stack-overflow-take-advantage-of)
<sup>2</sup> [Should one downvote an "average" question just because it's highly upvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137315/downvoting-average-mass-upvote-question)
<sup>3</sup> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/
<sup>4</sup> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104832/178438
<sup>5</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil
<sup>6</sup> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/182862
<sup>7</sup> [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/182862)