# ¿Es legítimo pedir reputaciones?

Tags: discusión

En varias ocaciones he visto pidiendo reputaciones al autor de la pregunta, solo por el hecho que hayan contestado y quizás también por el sacrificio que hayan tenido en responder.

Un ejemplo:

> Dale +1 al menos por contestar!

¿Es legítimo pidiendo *limosna* al autor por reputaciones?

Comment: No, pero toma un +1 por preguntarlo ;-)

Comment: Bromas aparte, creo que absolutamente no: los votos sirven para medir la calidad del contenido. Si algo está bien, se vota positivamente; si está mal, negativamente; si no aporta demasiado, no se vota. Todo lo que sea votar por elementos ajenos a la calidad es andar un camino peliagudo que no nos ayuda como comunidad. Ante textos como _Dale +1 al menos por contestar_ no cabe más que ignorarlos, eliminarlos de la publicación o reportarlos si son comentarios para que no ocupen el espacio destinado a la publicación en sí.

Comment: @fedorqui deberías convertir tu comentario en una respuesta :)

Comment: El uso de la palabra limosna para hacer referencia a las acciones de otros usuarios no es la mejor forma de expresar una opinión. Aunque sea metafóricamente y en cursiva.

Comment: Yo suelo decirle al usuario que preguntó cuando es novato que de un +1 al usuario que le dio una buena respuesta. Aunque yo no haya colaborado en la pregunta. Pues creo es una buena práctica hacerlo, porque alguien se tomó la molestia de responder, y si la respuesta fue buena se merece una +1 al menos por parte del autor de la pregunta. Hay mucha gente que no da esos puntos que tanto merecen los que responden. Supongo que hago bien.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dije en los comentarios:

> (...) creo que absolutamente no: los votos sirven para medir la calidad del contenido. Si algo está bien, se vota positivamente; si está mal, negativamente; si no aporta demasiado, no se vota. Todo lo que sea votar por elementos ajenos a la calidad es andar un camino peliagudo que no nos ayuda como comunidad. Ante textos como Dale +1 al menos por contestar no cabe más que ignorarlos, eliminarlos de la publicación o reportarlos si son comentarios para que no ocupen el espacio destinado a la publicación en sí.

Aprovecho para expandirlo un poco:

Desde el momento que mencionas la frase *Dale +1 al menos por contestar!*, nos podemos ceñir al caso en el que se pide el voto positivo. Esto lo explica la FAQ en [¿Cuándo debería votar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1076/83):

> Por supuesto, en cualquier caso, la respuesta **debe** responder la pregunta. (...)
>
> - La respuesta es clara.
>   - La respuesta explica el concepto de fondo. He visto muchas respuestas en SOes que dan la solución pero no el "por qué". A estas respuestas no suelo votarles en contra, pero tampoco a favor.
>
> Nota: [No votes a favor *solamente* para liberar la respuesta de un voto negativo innecesario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137315/downvoting-average-mass-upvote-question).

Observamos claramente que en ningún momento menciona otros elementos ajenos a la calidad de la respuesta. Cosas como:

- Simpatía por la persona
- Esfuerzo mostrado
- Compensar votos negativos
- Estado de las bolsas mundiales
- ...

... no pueden influir a la hora de votar. Al fin y al cabo, el modelo de Stack Exchange es meritocrático: lo bueno recibe votos por parte de la comunidad para que esta se beneficie de ese triaje.

El [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ya incide en esta filosofía:

> Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. Lo construyes y lo administras tú como parte de la red de sitios de preguntas y respuestas de Stack Exchange. Con tu ayuda, trabajamos juntos para crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español.
>
> Las buenas respuestas obtienen votos a favor y suben a los primeros puestos.
>
> Las mejores respuestas se muestran primero para que siempre sea fácil encontrarlas.

Por lo que debemos ser partícipes de ella y, sobre todo, pensar en el futuro visitante de una pregunta en la que hemos navegado. O en nosotros mismos: cuando entre en una cuestión sobre un tema que no conozco demasiado, ¿acaso no valoraré que las respuestas buenas sean las que estén arriba? ¿acaso me ayudará ver respuestas malas en la parte alta porque fueron votadas por motivos ajenos a su calidad? Al contrario, generará muchas dudas y dejará de ser una pregunta-respuesta útil.

Eso sí, el Recorrido también nos ilustra en el sentido humano:

> Nuestro objetivo es contar con las mejores respuestas para cada pregunta, por lo que si ves preguntas o respuestas que se pueden mejorar, puedes editarlas.
>
> Utiliza los comentarios para pedir más información o para aclarar una pregunta o respuesta.
>   Recuerda: Todos estamos aquí para aprender; así que, sé amable y ayuda a los demás.

Es decir que si te encuentras con comentarios del tipo *Dale +1 al menos por contestar!* podemos hacer muchas cosas:

- Dar las gracias por la respuesta
- Analizar y retroalimentar la respuesta con nuestro punto de vista.
- Reportar el comentario como "muy conversador", más que nada porque es irrelevante.

Comment: Perfektus... creo que con esta respuesta esta todo dicho.. Tomen su ... nooo  mejor una [cerve](http://data.whicdn.com/images/156612114/large.jpg) :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Me parece que todavía hay muchos que no captan que las respuestas no solo son para el beneficio del autor original de la pregunta, sino más que todo para los futuros visitantes buscando solución a sus problemas.  Por lo que a la larga, por más buena motivación que tangamos, dar votos positivos sin tomar en cuenta la calidad de la respuesta hace más daño que bien, tanto a los futuros visitantes, como a la reputación del sitio en sí.

Comment: Perfecta respuesta, he votado a favor de esta aportación.

Comment: "Dale +1 al menos por contestar!" es un ejemplo. Afirmar que un ejemplo significa que debemos ceñirnos al caso del ejemplo es un error. Una pregunta puede ser más general y puede merecer respuestas más generales que los ejemplos que incluye. La información que da esta respuesta me parece correcta pero insuficiente.

Comment: @Jose mi frase es _Desde el momento que mencionas la frase Dale +1 al menos por contestar!, nos podemos ceñir al caso en el que se pide el voto positivo_ y con ella quiero decir que simplemente hablaré del caso del voto positivo, no del negativo.

Comment: Eres libre de ceñirte a ese caso si así lo deseas. A mi me parece un error limitar una respuesta a un caso reducido pudiendo responder al caso general, Lo segundo me parece más útil.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, lo que sí habría que solicitar es que al menos una de las respuestas se marque como solución (siempre que al menos una solucione el problema). A mi personalmente me parece una falta de respeto por parte de algunos usuarios que hacen preguntas y la mitad de las veces se "_olvidan_" de marcar una respuesta como solución... no es por los puntos que te puedan dar sino por que así se pierde parte de la efectividad de StackOverflow

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo @eferion, a veces uno se queda con sensación de haber sido utilizado :) Hay quien utiliza comentarios del tipo: _Si te ha sido de utilidad la respuesta, recuerda que puedes aceptarla apretando la marca que hay bajo la puntuación de la publicación, haciéndola pasar de gris a verde. Lee al respecto en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers)_. También es bueno que nos pase a veces para pararnos a pensar: ¿es esta pregunta lo suficientemente genérica como para ser útil a más gente? ¿Vale realmente la pena contestarla? Porque a veces no.

Comment: @fedorqui si me pusiese estricto a la hora de seleccionar las preguntas a contestar creo que no respondería a la mitad de ellas. Muchas preguntas son de gente que está aprendiendo y ya sea por cabezonería, desidia, pasotismo o simple despiste cometen errores tontos que luego no saben solucionar. El problema es que esos errores son endémicos en esa fase del aprendizaje y, si no se responde la primera llegará una segunda, una tercera... creo que todos conocemos ese camino.

Comment: @eferion sí, ese es un dilema al que todos nos enfrentamos. Por lo que veo tus respuestas son muy potentes en cuanto a que van más allá de responder al detalle específico. Eso es fantástico, pues servirán de mucha ayuda a los que se encuentren en esta situación en el futuro. Ese trabajo se complementaría bien con una búsqueda de preguntas-respuestas canónicas cuando ves que una duda-error se repite especialmente. También creo interesante editar las preguntas para hacerlas genéricas en la medida de lo posible y que así no queden como algo muy específico de lo que ya nadie más se beneficia.

Comment: @fedorqui Editar las preguntas daría para tres o cuatro entradas nuevas en Meta... por lo menos para intentar sentar unas bases más o menos concretas para los que estamos activos. Eso sin contar con que hay usuarios que todavía se ofenden cuando les editas la pregunta y la vuelven a restaurar ...

Answer (score 10):

Depende.

No creo que se deba pedir limosna como tal, pero habría que diferenciar entre unos mensajes y otros dependiendo del contexto. Si sin ningún motivo el autor del post (pregunta o respuesta) u otra persona pide puntos por "*Dale +1 al menos por contestar!*", esos mensajes debería ser ignorados.

Pero... si en una respuesta, la persona que preguntó (u otro usuario) comenta "*Esto me sirvió de mucha ayuda*" o "*Esto solucionó mi problema*" pero no realiza ninguna acción al respecto, no veo nada malo en decir algo en la línea de "*Vota positivo*" o "*Acepta la respuesta*". En ese caso, más que mendigar lo consideraría recordar al usuario cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: Muy pertinente el caso que menciona Alvaro, creo que si es para ayudar a un usuario a saber como funciona el sitio si es permitido

Comment: Muy de acuerdo. Cuando un usuaro agradece en un comentario una respuesta y no le da un voto el decirle que vote es educarle en el uso del sitio, no es pedir limosna.

Comment: No me refería si la respuesta le ayudo al OP y luego le avisa que lo acepte como respuesta... sino mas a los usuarios que piden al OP un +1 por haber contestado aunque en realidad no le hayan solucionado el problema... y ya lo he visto varias veces :/ y @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos - Se puede agradecer una respuesta (Como: Gracias por tu tiempo pero no me sirvió) pero si no le sirvió al OP no pidas votos por tomarte el tiempo en contestar...

Comment: @aldanux Yo también animaría a considerar la opción de votar en el caso de un usuario que dice "Gracias pero no me ha servido". +1 si la respuesta es correcta y responde a la pregunta aunque no le ha servido. -1 si es incorrecta o no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: @aldanux Entiendo tu punto, pero creo que si hay diferencia en los casos de ""limosna" y "educar"

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Es legítimo pidiendo limosna al autor por reputaciones?

**NO.**

El sistema de reputación en Stack Exchange no es una moneda ni debe pensarse que lo es.

Answer (score 3):

**No** hay lugar para mendigar votos en SO, ya tomando en cuenta que la idea de la comunidad es de manejar las publicaciones en un ambiente informativo, evitando la charla y dejando aquella a donde pertenece. Prefería cualquier momento de dejar un comentario entretenido que pedir votos en favor. Aparte de eso es patético mendigar por algo solamente porque la otra parte no tiene la decencia de valorar lo que se le entrega.

**Sin embargo** lo encuentro valido de explicar a OPs, que dan las gracias por comentario y explicando como les solucionó el problema, mientras ignoran las herramientas de hacerlo en la manera SO: por aceptar y/o votar. Es una buena oportunidad para identificar usuarios que aparentemente no entienden el concepto de una meritocracia para dirigirlos a una explicación o entregarselos con pocas palabras.

En sintesis hay que aplicar criterio en que reacción en el caso particular tiene mayor beneficio para la plataforma en si.

Answer (score -5):

**SÍ** cuando se pide sin indicar el sentido.

Siempre es legítimo pedir reputación. Es bueno animar a la gente a que vote. Sin indicar en qué sentido.

Lo mínimo que se merece quien se te toma la molestia de escribir una respuesta es que el que pregunta se detenga a pensar si se merece un +1/-1/aceptar y lo marque de acuerdo a su opinión.

**NO** es legítimo pedir que se vote en un sentido u otro. Salvo que el usuario haya expresado cláramente que la respuesta le parece correcta/incorrecta en cuyo caso sí es legítimo animarle a que vote +1/-1

Con lo que la respuesta a tu ejemplo sería no, pues indica el sentido del voto. Y a la pregunta del título un rotundo sí.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53003/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-es-legitimo-pedir-reputaciones).