# ¿Cuál es el criterio para votar a favor en una pregunta?

Tags: discusión, votos, preguntas, votos-positivos

De acuerdo a [este post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1076/42433) (y sus contenidos relacionados), una pregunta bien formulada debe considerar los siguientes puntos:

> #### Voto a favor
>
> (elige una)
>
> - La pregunta es clara y muestra esfuerzo de investigación.
> - La pregunta es muy buena (en caso de preguntas divertidas, esto también puede funcionar)
> - La pregunta  es útil para otros usuarios.
>
> Nota: No votes a favor **por el solo hecho de** liberar una
> publicación de un voto negativo innecesario<sup>4</sup>.

Me encontré una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76953/validar-hora-pedido-y-hora-entrega-para-que-sea-mayor-a-24-horas-con-modelos-di/76975?noredirect=1#comment142377_76975) donde, a mi juicio, los puntos anteriores no se cumplen, de hecho la pregunta se ha modificado un par de ocasiones conforme se han resuelto los problemas (a modo de *debug*); sin embargo tiene muchos votos a favor (comparado contra el promedio).

Mi duda es, ¿por qué los votos a favor? Me interesa entender bien el criterio ya que constantemente busco mejorar el contenido del sitio y posiblemente no esté utilizando el criterio adecuado, lo cual resultaría contraproducente.

Comment: Uno fue mío, me pareció bastante completa la pregunta, pero debo decir que no sé nada del tema, nunca manejé Ruby. Además fue pedido [en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38001123#38001123) que se votara a favor, de parte de otro moderador.

Comment: @ArtEze Lo entiendo y creo conocer del lenguaje/tecnología en específico no hace diferencia. Y gracias por tu respuesta, pues me sirve para conocer mejor como evaluar una pregunta.

Comment: En general, según la publicación que comentas, podemos votar a favor, cuando _en nuestra opinión_ la pregunta cumple cualquiera de las tres características o cualquier combinación de ellas (no las 3 al mismo tiempo). La clave aquí es que los votos son _subjetivos_, es decir, no precisan de decisiones basadas en datos verificables, solo en percepciones. Por eso _a tu juicio_, la pregunta no debía ser votada a favor... seguro que tienes razón, pero un moderador pidió que votaran y tal vez quienes votaron __no tomaron en consideración__  si la pregunta merecía el voto o no.

Comment: Por cierto, los criterios no deben cambiar solo porque en un caso excepcional un moderador pidió que se votara a favor. Los casos especiales no deben usarse para establecer normas. Se deben tratar como casos especiales.

Comment: @toledano Me queda claro ahora, no lo había identificado como un caso especial, pero ahora lo entiendo. Mi duda fue justo al ver varios votos donde hacía evidente que _mi juicio_ era el que estaba mal; pero ya con esta respuesta me queda claro. Gracias!

Comment: @toledano Fuera del tema de la pregunta pero: ¿alguna razón por la cual tu respuesta se hizo en un comentario y no como respuesta?

Comment: Porque me siento más en libertad al escribir un comentario. Los comentarios pueden borrarse sin dejar rastros, ¿sabes? Las respuestas no desaparecen aunque las borres. Los usuarios con los privilegios adecuados pueden ver las publicaciones eliminadas.

Comment: @toledano los comentarios tampoco se indexan y no aparecen como respuesta (un usuario que busca una pregunta, puede ver que tiene 0 respuestas, no entrar y no leer tu comentario con la solución perfecta). Escribir respuestas en los comentarios "para no dejar rastro" (o por cualquier excusa) es un mal uso del sitio

Comment: Y que la gente vote en modo borrego porque un usuario (sea o no sea moderador) lo pida en el chat sólo demuestra que esos usuarios no saben cómo usar sus votos correctamente, y que la comunidad puede no ser tan madura como pensamos.

Comment: @Gerry considero que lo tuyo a diferencia de ser *mal juicio* solo es una opinión diferente. Considera que, si a tu criterio, es una pregunta que no cumple con lo indicado arriba, puedes votar en contra o no votar. Todo sigue siendo subjetivo.

Comment: @ArtEze *Además fue pedido en el chat que se votara a favor, de parte de otro moderador* ante estos casos, un moderador simplemente es un usuario más de la plataforma, su opinión cuenta como tal, es como si taparas el diamante y vieras que un usuario pide que se vote a favor de una pregunta. ¿Es necesario? La respuesta la dicta tu juicio.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Solo estaba explicando un posible motivo por el que tuvo 4 votos... En mi caso, acepté la invitación, miré la publicación, y como me pareció que era buena pregunta, voté a favor.

Comment: @ArtEze entiendo que te parezca que merece voto a favor porque así lo consideras. Lo que me parece extraño y hasta un poco incorrecto es seguir a una persona que pidió los votos, aunque sea moderador. Y es lo que expones como parte de tu motivación a votar a favor. Hay que tener cuidado con la redacción.

Answer (score 1):

Después de ver los comentarios y, sobre todo el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38001123#38001123) al que se hace referencia en los mismos, puedo tener ya una respuesta concreta a mi pregunta:

> ¿por qué los votos a favor?

La ayuda proporcionada al usuario que realizó la pregunta se había extendido mucho como para mantener la conversación en comentarios, por lo que un moderador ofreció una sala de chat; sin embargo el usuario no podría acceder hasta tener un mínimo de 20 puntos, razón por la que se pidió ayuda para subir su puntuación (a través de votos a favor) y así poder entrar al chat y continuar con la ayuda.

Bajo ese contexto me parece que la decisión (y votación a favor) fue la correcta, ya que así se pudo dar un mejor apoyo al usuario. Aunque creo que esta discusión pertenecería a otra pregunta.

Comment: Ese fue el motivo, sí, pero el pedido de que se votara creo que fue un error (que yo alguna vez también cometí), y si alguien voto a favor sólo por ese pedido, no creo que haya tomado una buena decisión. El sitio no es para asistir las necesidades de un solo usuario.

Comment: @Mariano ¿Existe alguna opción alterna para esos casos? Más de una vez he pensado "esto podría solucionarse en minutos en un chat" pero el usuario no puede entrar a una sala.

Comment: La única forma de que un usuario de <20 pueda hablar es [que un moderador le dé acceso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90972/304899). No obstante, el chat es para usuarios que ya demostraron conocer el uso correcto del sitio. El chat generado desde una pregunta no es para que se resuelva el problema de un usuario, sino para terminar de aclarar la pregunta, y luego editarla y responderla **en el sitio**. Que sea un usuario nuevo no lo excusa de poder describir y plantear un problema correctamente, bien redactado en una pregunta.

Comment: Dicho esto, sí creo que el umbral para votar +1 a un usuario nuevo es mucho más bajo. Y yo voto +1 en la revisión de Primeras Preguntas a cualquier pregunta que esté bien expresada y que contenga el código que describe al problema y se comprende.